# Getting an error "((System.IO.FileNotFoundException)(the specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: exception, oracle11g, ioexception

I am getting an error while running a .Net application.

The main problem which I feel is due to the `Oracle.Data.Access`.I made the project build to 32 bit as it had some problem of [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) exception

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess,
>   Version=2.111.7.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

Making my project to 32 bit actually solved this Oracle problem, but then the following error is thrown:

> ((System.IO.FileNotFoundException)(the specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I am actually trying to write to a file in the function from where the exception is being thrown.The file location is defined in app.config

```
<printJobsSection outputRootPath="D:\ANKIT_print\">
<formatterTemplatesSection templateRootPath="D:\\Print NySag FeatureDEV\\" defaultFileNameFmt="{COUNTRY}_{DEBT}_{CUST}_{ATRNY}_{CREATED}_{TMPL}_{ID}.pdf">
```

Is this error due to 32 or 64 bit as my Windows 7 version is 64 bit and the project is built using 32 bit or something else

Please suggest the possible outcome of this error.

Comment: you don't say which type of project? ASP.NET? Winforms? also why are you referencing a file? Why not use the fill in the project by adding it as a reference? if you are using ASP.NET and hosting it in IIS, be sure that the 32bit apps are enabled in the apppool

Comment: It is possible the the dll cannot be picked up in x64. If the dll is older when the newer compatibility changes came through then you would not be able to load this. I've had this problem with some exceedingly old dlls that I simply couldn't pick up until I forced the app to open in 32 mode

Comment: Its an Asp.net applicatiuon (.net Version 3.0) I am trying to write something to the file which is existing locally and 32 bit application are enabled in apppool

Comment: This is a run time error? System.IO.FileNotFoundException and 'trying to write to a file' ... well, the file exists? Your last question: Windows 64 bit can run both 32 and 64 bit compiled programs, this wont be your problem, assuming all dependencies run with 32&64 bit (e.g. Access OleDB drivers aren't supported in 64bit).

Comment: Ya I am getting this error during runtime.The file exists(I have checked that while debugging).Any suggestion for Oracle.DataAccess exception "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.7.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified".                                          I have checked the registry of this file in GAC also